# Fragment OnclickListener RecycleView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Hello I am having a hard time to implement this,I havent found any example to do it.I have gone up to this point myself but I am stuck!Any help would be appreciated

```
public class JobsFragment extends Fragment{
    private List<JobsLists> jobsLists;
    private RecyclerView recycle;
    private FirebaseFirestore fb;
    private FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<JobsLists, JobsViewHolder> adapter;
    private static final String TAG ="" ;

    public JobsFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View jobsView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_jobs, container, false);
        recycle =  jobsView.findViewById(R.id.recycle);
        recycle.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this.getActivity()));

        fb = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        Query query = 
        recycle.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());

        FirestoreRecyclerOptions<JobsLists> options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<JobsLists>()
                .setQuery(query, JobsLists.class)
                .build();
        adapter = new FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<JobsLists, JobsViewHolder>(options) {
            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull  JobsViewHolder holder, final int position,@NonNull JobsLists jobsmodel) {
                jobsmodel = jobsLists.get(position);

                holder.setTitle(jobsmodel.getTitle());

                holder.cv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Context context = v.getContext();
//                    Intent intent = new Intent(context, JobView.class);
//                    intent.putExtra("title", .get(position));
//                    intent.putExtra("description", .get(position));
//                    context.startActivity(intent);
                        Toast.makeText(context,"clicked="+ jobsmodel.getTitle(position)),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                });
            }

            @NonNull
            @Override
            public JobsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.custom_card, parent, false);
                return new JobsViewHolder(view);
            }

        };
        recycle.setAdapter(adapter);
        return jobsView;

    }

    private class JobsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder   {
        private View view;
       private CardView cv;
        JobsViewHolder(final View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            view = itemView;
            cv = itemView.findViewById(R.id.job_post);

        }


        private TextView ti;

        public void setTitle(String name) {
            ti = view.findViewById(R.id.title);
            ti.setText(name);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        adapter.startListening();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        if (adapter != null) {
            adapter.stopListening();
        }
    } }
```

And I cant really pass params to the fragment constructor as many examples suggest!
I have seen examples where they implement OnclickListener but I don't know why it doesnt work in my class.Please give me some directions ,I am trying to learn!

Comment: Have you tried `holder.view.setOnClickListener(..` instead of  `holder.cv.setOnClickListener(`?

Comment: I have most problems are with the Joblist class,I cant seem to get the clicked item @B.M

Comment: `holder.view.setOnClickListener(..` didn't work too ?

Comment: @B.M there is also this problem where it doesnt show all the items

Comment: @B.M the problem is this line here `code jobsmodel.getTitle(position))`

Comment: What's the problem there ,does the application crash or what ?

Comment: @B.M cannot resolve method makeText(contect,java.lang.string

Comment: Replace that line with `Toast.makeText(context,"clicked="+ jobsmodel.getTitle(position),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`

Comment: @B.M You did it,please answer to this question so that I can mark it as right,also please if you could include why it doesnt show all my items in the recycleview some show some dont

Comment: Are you sure that the list contains all the items you want to show ?

Comment: yes the title doesnt show & I dont know why? @B.M I thought that maybe my layout had the problem but no,its the same as others very strange

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `Toast.makeText(context,"clicked="+jobsmodel.getTitle(position)),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()` with
 `Toast.makeText(context,"clicked="+jobsmodel.getTitle(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`

Answer (score 0):

I always implement the onclickListener under the constructor of the holder class , so, try to implement this under JobsViewHolder(final View itemView)

```
cv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Context context = v.getContext();
                       Toast.makeText(itemView.getContext(),"clicked="+jobsmodel.getTitle(position)),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
```